# How to update textviews of list inside AsyncTask class method?

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask, textview

Stuck with this. 
I have `FirstAsyncTask`  which updates array `arr`[]
Iam updating images using another `ImageAdapter` . Please see code for details
I want to update each textview of List.  Follwoing code UPDATES imageviews but does not update textview. I want to setText of this textview with `arr`[] I updated in 
I am using following code inside `onPostExecute` of `FirstAsyncTask`:

```
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, dataList,
                    R.layout.list_item, arr, new int[] { R.id.name,
                            R.id.email, R.id.mobile });

setListAdapter(Ladapter);

        //HOW TO UPDATE TEXTVIEW WITH ARRAY arr[]?????

        list=(ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);

        // Create custom adapter for listview
        adapter=new ImageAdapter(MainActivity.this, msStringS);//updater of images
        //Set adapter to listview
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Can anyone give me CustomList adapter code for this case? Please

Answer (score 0):

Do it in the postExecute method of the AsyncTask class

After doInBackground(), return the object that you want to populate the list.

This will then be passed to onPostExecute() and you can initialise the list adapter there.

```
private class LoadList extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<String>> {
        @Override protected List<String> doInBackground(Void... params) {
            ArrayList<String> listContents = new ArrayList<String>();

            listContents.add("Item one");
            listContents.add("Item two");
            listContents.add("Item three");

            return listContents;
        }

        @Override protected void onPostExecute(List<String> listContents) {
            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, listContents,
                    R.layout.list_item, arr, new int[] { R.id.name,
                    R.id.email, R.id.mobile });

            mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Its the same code I am using. setListAdapter() is not settiing my textview.

Comment: setListAdapter will only work if you are extending a ListActivity or ListFragment. I've modified my answer, try that:

mListView.setAdapter(adapter);

Answer (score 0):

we can update UserInterface inside doInBackground() by using runOnUiThread concept. but this is bad practice. as sam said kindly update user inferface in onPostExe which will give smooth interaction.

else you can use runOnUiThread by

Sample.this.runOnThrea..{ public void run(){ . update ui here.} }

Comment: Can you give me code of updating textview with array or arraylist? tobe exucuted in run() ??

Comment: do you mean the entire code for update the view. if so , then how do i know textview object.