# Updating textviews and imageview in same list using adapters updates only one thing

Tags: android, android-asynctask, textview, imageview

I have a list in MainActivity. I am updating textviews in that list with AsyncTask. This list has multiple textviews and one ImageView.

I want to update both(imageviews and textviews) .

I am extending my question:
[How to update textviews of list inside AsyncTask class method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28238194/how-to-update-textviews-of-list-inside-asynctask-class-method)
I am using following code which updates ONLY ONE which is a problem:

```
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, dataList,
                    R.layout.list_item, arr, new int[] { R.id.name,
                            R.id.email, R.id.mobile });

setListAdapter(Ladapter);

        //HOW TO UPDATE TEXTVIEW WITH ARRAY arr[]?????

        list=(ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);

        // Create custom adapter for listview
        adapter=new ImageAdapter(MainActivity.this, msStringS);//updater of images
        //Set adapter to listview
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Is it because wrong ordering?BTW I tried all possibilities? I might missing something basic? OR its impossible??

listview_row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:background="@drawable/bar_bg_thin"
           android:paddingTop="0dip" android:layout_gravity="top"
         >
        <TableRow >
            <LinearLayout 
                  android:layout_width="70dp"
                  android:layout_height="match_parent"
                  android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                  android:paddingTop="5dp"
                  android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                  >
                <ImageView
                 android:layout_gravity="left|top" 
                  android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                  android:id="@+id/image"
                  android:src="@drawable/stub"
                   android:layout_width="50dip" 
                  android:layout_height="50dip"
                  />
              </LinearLayout>
  <TableLayout 
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:paddingTop="0dip" android:layout_gravity="top"
            >
            <TableRow>       
               <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/outletname"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                    android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:layout_span="1"
                    />
              </TableRow>
              <TableRow>          
                 <TextView
                    android:text=""
                    android:id="@+id/logourl"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                    android:textSize="11sp"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dip"
                    android:gravity="left"/>
              </TableRow>
            </TableLayout>

               <ImageView
                  android:layout_height="30dp"
                  android:layout_width="30dp"
                  android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                  android:background="@drawable/dislike1"
                  android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                  android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                  android:gravity="left"
                  />
       </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Comment: Can you be more clear?

Comment: Updated questions. please look

Comment: Hi, what's `Ladapter`? and why do you instantiate `adapter` twice? And are you in a `ListActivity`? and where's `ImageAdapter`? Trying to help, but not understanding what you want to do...

Comment: Ladapter is Listadapter and and adapter is Imageadapter

Comment: Using ladpter I'm setting textviews and using Imageadapter I'm updating images with respectively urls

Comment: Problem is in onPostExecute method I don't knoe how to update both as list.setadapter will set one